# Scriptrunner Create issue and assign to existing epic

Tags: groovy, jira, epic, scriptrunner-for-jira

While creating a new issue using scriptrunner, I would like to assign it an existing epic. it seems the issue.setCustomFieldValue(epicLinkCustomField) is not working. any help would be greatly appreciated. everything else works fine, im able to set name, summary, tittle, prio, description, assign reporter, projectkey, issue context, and issue type.
The code I have is below.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.context.IssueContext
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.context.IssueContextImpl
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.config.manager.PrioritySchemeManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def date = new Date()
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

// the project key under which the issue will get created
final projectKey = 'SEC'
// stores status
final statusKey = 'AN QUE'
// the issue type for the new issue
final issueTypeName = 'Task'
// user with that user key will be the reporter of the issue
final reporterKey = 'MV108788'
// the summary of the new issue
final summary = 'test' + date
// the priority of the new issue
final priorityName = 'Low'
// sets description
final description = 'this is a decription'
//epic
final epicIssueKey = 'test'

def issueService = ComponentAccessor.issueService
def constantsManager = ComponentAccessor.constantsManager
def loggedInUser = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.loggedInUser
def prioritySchemeManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(PrioritySchemeManager)

//finds epic
def epicLinkCustomField = ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects().findByName(epicIssueKey)
//finds status key
def status = ComponentAccessor.constantsManager.getStatusByName(statusKey)
//finds project key
def project = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectKey)
assert project : "Could not find project with key $projectKey"
//finds issue types
def issueType = constantsManager.allIssueTypeObjects.findByName(issueTypeName)
assert issueType : "Could not find issue type with name $issueTypeName"
// if we cannot find user with the specified key or this is null, then set as a reporter the logged in user
def reporter = ComponentAccessor.userManager.getUserByKey(reporterKey) ?: loggedInUser
// if we cannot find the priority with the given name or if this is null, then set the default priority
def issueContext = new IssueContextImpl(project, issueType) as IssueContext
// finds priority
def priorityId = constantsManager.priorities.findByName(priorityName)?.id ?: prioritySchemeManager.getDefaultOption(issueContext)

//sets all issue settings
def issueInputParameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters().with {
setStatusId(statusId) //not working
setProjectId(project.id)
setDescription(description)
setIssueTypeId(issueType.id)
setReporterId(reporter.name)
setSummary(summary)
setPriorityId(priorityId)
issue.setCustomFieldValue(epicLinkCustomField)
}


def validationResult = issueService.validateCreate(loggedInUser, issueInputParameters)
assert validationResult.valid : validationResult.errorCollection

def result = issueService.create(loggedInUser, validationResult)
assert result.valid : result.errorCollection
```

Comment: Try to use https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/issue/CustomFieldManager.html#getCustomFieldObjectsByName-java.lang.String- maybe you have multiple custom fields with the same name?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working" ? Any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass epic issue object as a second parameter:

```
issue.setCustomFieldValue(epicLinkCustomField, epicIssue)
```

To get the epic issue you can use something like this:

```
epicIssue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueByCurrentKey("EPIC-KEY")
```